# Difference between messages with CN and WM prefixes

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-messages

When looking at Delphi source code, I often see messages declarations from the Windows API, such as `CN_NOTIFY` and `WM_NOTIFY`. I would like to know the differences between them and when they should be used?

Comment: CN_... and CM_... messages are proprietary VCL messages. You need to study VCL source code for any specific message, there's no general guide.

Comment: The difference is WM stands for "Window Message", CN stands for "Control Notification", CM stands for "Control Message".

Comment: @IInspectable: CN-prefixed messages won't be in Petzold's book. They are Delphi-specific VCL internal messages.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: I'm fairly sure the question changed in between me making that suggesting and now. It used to ask for different message types (commands and notifications). The difference between those is explained in Petzold's book. It's a fundamental distinction, that's relevant regardless of the GUI framework in use.

Comment: @IInspectable: the question was not edited, AFAICT. And CN_ messages are really Delphi specific, as I said, so yes, they are defined in the framework. They are very likely not found in Petzold's book.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`WM` messages are used by the Win32 API, and end user code.

`CM` and `CN` messages are used internally by the VCL.

When the VCL processes certain `WM` notifications from the Win32 API, like `WM_COMMAND` and `WM_NOTIFY`, which are sent from a child control to its parent window, the VCL reflects them as `CN` messages (`CN_COMMAND` and `CN_NOTIFY`) back to the child that sent them. This allows VCL controls to handle their own notifications.

Comment: As always, you are a savior @Remy